# Interface Evolution - Inherited return type

Tags: java, inheritance

i have an application with developing datamodel (the app handles old and new data).
Now i want to overwrite the return type of the method with an evolution of the original return type:

```
public interface Section {

List<Item> getItems();
}

public interface Item {
    String getName();
}

public interface ItemEvolution extends Item {
      String getEvolution();
}
public interface SectionEvolution extends Section {
      List<ItemEvolution> getItems();
}
```

in this constellation i get an incompatible return type at getItems(), but i don't break the parent interface, cause ItemEvolution extends Item.

How can i handle that?

I am using Java 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible return types for method when returning subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456675/incompatible-return-types-for-method-when-returning-subclass)

Comment: use wildcards -- `List<? extends Item>`

Comment: no duplicate - i saw that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<ItemEvolution>` is not compatible with `List<Item>` (because you can add an `Item` to the latter but not the former). This is a common pitfall with generics.

One solution is to use `List<? extends Item>` as the superclass's return type in `Section`:

```
public interface Section {
    List<? extends Item> getItems();
}

public interface SectionEvolution extends Section {
    // Or List<? extends ItemEvolution> if you might want to override this again.
    List<ItemEvolution> getItems();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use generics.

```
public interface Section<E extends Item> {

    List<E> getItems();
}

public interface Item {
    String getName();
}

public interface ItemEvolution extends Item {
    String getEvolution();
}

public interface SectionEvolution extends Section<ItemEvolution> {
}
```

Comment: thank you - i thought, i checked that before - i was to frantic.

Answer (score 1):

This one nicely explains why your case is not working:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

[image]

So  `List<ItemEvolution>` is not a subclass of  `List<Item>` - So you need to use generics with wildcards as described here - actually this article explains exactly your case.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

[image]